# Will I receive all the SMS on my iPhone although it has been disconnected for some time?

Tags: iphone, sms

After having my iPhone disconnected for some time, will all the text messages people have sent me, arrive to the phone once I reconnect it?

Answer (score 1):

Usually SMS messages have a 'lifetime' of around 9 days - this is set by the carrier.

iMessages should be delivered the next time you connect your iPhone to a network.